# JSON data to HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have this set of JSON .Now,I am able to access the objects inside it. But,problem is I can't get the output as desired. I have two types of outputs to be displayed :

1. real_name
2. text

But I am getting real_name and text all at a time.

I have tried this method

```
document.getElementById("a1").innerHTML += text + "<br>";
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>hi</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Convert a string written in JSON format, into a JavaScript object.</h2>

<p id="output"></p>
<div id="a1"></div>
<div id="a2"></div>

<script>
var obj = [{
    "client_msg_id": "3a223f8d-b5aa-4c9c-9b63-045ec6f90b58",
    "type": "message",
    "text": "hey there",
    "source_team": "TN4AF0V5W",
    "team": "TN4AF0V5W",
    "user_profile": {
      "real_name": "marvelmohinish99",
      "team": "TN4AF0V5W"
    }
  },
  {
    "client_msg_id": "3a223f8d-b5aa-4c9c-9b63-045ec6f90b58",
    "type": "message",
    "text": "welcome",
    "source_team": "TN4AF0V5W",
    "team": "TN4AF0V5W",
    "user_profile": {
      "real_name": "marvelmohinish99",
      "team": "TN4AF0V5W"
    }
  },
  {
    "client_msg_id": "3a223f8d-b5aa-4c9c-9b63-045ec6f90b58",
    "type": "message",
    "text": "Help me",
    "source_team": "TN4AF0V5W",
    "team": "TN4AF0V5W",
    "user_profile": {
      "real_name": "marvelmohinish99",
      "team": "TN4AF0V5W"
    }
  }
];
for(var i=0;i<=obj.length;i++){

  var text = obj[i].text;

  var source_team = obj[i].source_team;

  var user_profile = obj[i].user_profile;

  var real_name = user_profile.real_name;

  console.log(text);
  console.log(real_name);

  document.getElementById("a1").innerHTML += text + "<br>";
  document.getElementById("a2").innerHTML += real_name + "<br>";
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

expected output-

```
marvelmohinish99<br>
hey there<br>
marvelmohinish99<br>
welcome<br> 
marvelmohinish99<br>
help me<br>
```

Actual Output-

```
hey there<br>
welcome<br>
help me<br>

marvelmohinish99<br>
marvelmohinish99<br>
marvelmohinish99<br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to append this content into the same element instead of seperate elements. Here's an example:

```js
var obj = [{
    "client_msg_id": "3a223f8d-b5aa-4c9c-9b63-045ec6f90b58",
    "type": "message",
    "text": "hey there",
    "source_team": "TN4AF0V5W",
    "team": "TN4AF0V5W",
    "user_profile": {
      "real_name": "marvelmohinish99",
      "team": "TN4AF0V5W"
    }
  },
  {
    "client_msg_id": "3a223f8d-b5aa-4c9c-9b63-045ec6f90b58",
    "type": "message",
    "text": "welcome",
    "source_team": "TN4AF0V5W",
    "team": "TN4AF0V5W",
    "user_profile": {
      "real_name": "marvelmohinish99",
      "team": "TN4AF0V5W"
    }
  },
  {
    "client_msg_id": "3a223f8d-b5aa-4c9c-9b63-045ec6f90b58",
    "type": "message",
    "text": "Help me",
    "source_team": "TN4AF0V5W",
    "team": "TN4AF0V5W",
    "user_profile": {
      "real_name": "marvelmohinish99",
      "team": "TN4AF0V5W"
    }
  }
];

obj.forEach(function(x) {
  var entry = "<div>" + x.user_profile.real_name + "</div><div>" + x.text + "</div>";
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += entry;
});
```

```html
<h2>Convert a string written in JSON format, into a JavaScript object.</h2>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Here's another example, but this time we delay each entry by a couple of seconds. It's unclear if this is what you're asking for.

```js
var obj = [{
    "client_msg_id": "3a223f8d-b5aa-4c9c-9b63-045ec6f90b58",
    "type": "message",
    "text": "hey there",
    "source_team": "TN4AF0V5W",
    "team": "TN4AF0V5W",
    "user_profile": {
      "real_name": "marvelmohinish99",
      "team": "TN4AF0V5W"
    }
  },
  {
    "client_msg_id": "3a223f8d-b5aa-4c9c-9b63-045ec6f90b58",
    "type": "message",
    "text": "welcome",
    "source_team": "TN4AF0V5W",
    "team": "TN4AF0V5W",
    "user_profile": {
      "real_name": "marvelmohinish99",
      "team": "TN4AF0V5W"
    }
  },
  {
    "client_msg_id": "3a223f8d-b5aa-4c9c-9b63-045ec6f90b58",
    "type": "message",
    "text": "Help me",
    "source_team": "TN4AF0V5W",
    "team": "TN4AF0V5W",
    "user_profile": {
      "real_name": "marvelmohinish99",
      "team": "TN4AF0V5W"
    }
  }
];

obj.forEach(function(x, i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var entry = "<div class='name'>" + x.user_profile.real_name + "</div><div class='text'>" + x.text + "</div>";
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += entry;
  }, 2000 * i);
});
```

```css
.name {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: green;
}

.text {
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<h2>Convert a string written in JSON format, into a JavaScript object.</h2>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Yes this is perfect.Now,can I attach CSS styles to this? If so how?

Comment: Like, Now the answer is of class output right?Can we do anything such that the real_name is bolded and has bigger text and text has smaller and less weight compared to real_name.

Comment: You can add classes to your elements and define CSS rules for those classes. See the second example.

Comment: it's because all of them are div only right with output class how can we pass different css?

Comment: Can you please help me with how to change the class of this example?

Comment: Take a look at the second example, I have added two classes: `name` and `text`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your loop should look like this:

   `for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)`
   Not `i<= obj.length`.
2. When I run just your JS I get your expected result.
   https://repl.it/@robquan/Test12